# Symfony 3+: Custom form element template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4, symfony3.x

We are finally upgrading to Symfony 3 which however causes some issues.

Current problem I am trying to solve is https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Form/FormTypeInterface.html#method_getName witch has been deprecated.

`FormTypeInterface#getName()`  was used to create a nickname witch was used in twig form templates.

**Example custom form type:**

```
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType {

    // ...

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_custom';
    }

}
```

**Example template row in Twig:**

```
{% block my_custom_row %}

    {# ... #}

{% endblock %}
```

**Question:**

What is the naming convention for custom form types in Symfony 3+? I.e. how should I name the twig blocks to customize the form row/widget/error rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig block by default should be named as `FormType` class without `Type` suffix. ie. `my_custom_row` for `*_row` block.

Other, more custom way is to add function `getBlockPrefix()` (https://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormTypeInterface.html#method_getBlockPrefix). That function should return exactly the same block name prefix as `getName()` before, but this is optional and require only if block prefix is different than class name.

In Symfony4 is also available form option `block_name` that override defaults.